# How do I make a web page only show rows in a while loop if the user has scrolled to that part?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have a website where people upload random things, and the home page displays everything that has been posted in a while loop. I want to make it so it only shows that part of the page that the user has scrolled to instead of displaying all of the rows in that table. It takes about 20 seconds for the whole page to load and I want to narrow that down.

I have tried to use pagination, but I can't find any easy way to do it.

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "photos");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images
ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td><a href='view_news.php?id=".$row['id']."'><br><center><div id='img_div' class='boxx'>";
    echo "<img class='image' style='width:220px;height:124px;float:left;' src='images/".$row['image']."' >";
    echo "<h3>".htmlentities($row['title'])."</h3>";
    echo "<h5><b>By:&nbsp</b>".htmlentities($row['user'])."</h5>";
    echo "<h6>".htmlentities($row['date'])."</h6>";
    echo "<br></div></center></a></td>

    ";
}
?>
```

It displays all of them at once, but I want them to be displayed only when the user has scrolled to them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an ajax call. Once the user scrolls to the buttom of the page make an ajax call that will return you more rows and append them to the dom.

For ajax requests the easiet would be with jQuery

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: but what type of php/sql code would I need in order to display like 10 at a time instead of the whole thing repeating itself?

Comment: Well you will need to pass to the php script 2 query params limit and offset.
script.php?count=10&offset=0

On php
you can get those values with $_GET['count'] and $_GET['offset']

On sql
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $count ";

For more info check this
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-mysql-limit-clause/